How to access Authorization header in React application to extract JWT token sent by external Service?
I'm working on a React.Js application that receives a JWT token from external service as part of the Authorisation header for security reasons. I need to extract this token in my React component to authenticate user.
However, I'm not sure how to access the Authorisation header in my React application.
Can anyone suggest a reliable way to access the Authorisation header in a React application, so I can extract the JWT token sent by external service?
click to view image

i am using react hook useEffect and tried
const authHeader = axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];

But its not working

I'm not sure you have access to retrieve the value of your http header on the frontend. You can only set the authorization token on the header when sending your request to the server.

A client-side React app does not have access to http request headers. The http request headers are sent to the server, which processes the request and returns a HTML page that loads your JavaScript files followed by the browser running the code (your React app). What you are looking for is passing the Authorization header to your app which can be done in multiple ways, for example include data in the html response or set a cookie

Can you please provide some more detail , Or example if possible!

@MuhammadIbrahimJan it will make more sense if you can share how your app works with specific examples. Specifically for the request containing authorization: where does the request come from and where does it go?

In a third party mobile app, we are showing our react app in webview. third party app pass JWT auth token in header to our link. we need to get that token in react.js, decode that token and passess the data from decoded token to an API.
